# input and button side by side

Tags: html, css, input, vertical-alignment

Im working on a header for a website and i have a problem with search option.
I have include an `input` and a `button` tag. 
Thoose have to have a `vertical-align: middle;` and should be side by side.

I've try something but it doesn't work.
Can somebody explain why and how i fix that?

HTML:

```
    <div id="main_search">
        <input id="main_search_input" type="text" placeholder="Suchen" />
        <button id="search_button"><img src="search.png" width="20" style="border-left: 1px solid #D7D7D7; padding: 0 0 0 5px;" alt="" title="" /></button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main_search {
    float: right;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
#main_search_input {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important;
}
#search_button {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuWc2/)

Comment: Both `#main_search_input` and `#search_button` have `padding` set. so what are you trying to do when you say that they should be side by side? Are you trying to get them to have the same height and the same vertical position, or to be adjoining horizontally, or both?

Comment: There is a whitespace between your input and your button, remove that one and give your button a `margin: 0`.

Comment: @PetervanderWal is there another way to fix that, without remove the whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` and `button` elements are inline elements, as such by separating them by a newline in your code, this is effectively interpreted and rendered as a whitespace character, leading to a gap appearing between them.

To solve this, add:

```
input, button{
    margin:0;
}
```

Then remove the new line from between the elements in your HTML:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuWc2/3/)

```
<body>
    <div id="main_search">
        <input id="main_search_input" type="text" placeholder="Suchen" /><button id="search_button">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/TWG_Retina_Icons/24/magnifier.png" width="20" style="border-left: 1px solid #D7D7D7; padding: 0 0 0 5px;" />
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Alternatives

(also requiring setting no margins, per above)

[**Float the two elements so they push up against one another**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuWc2/5/)

[**Apply a `font-size:0` to `#main_search` so the space has a width of zero**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuWc2/6/)

Comment: the problem will fix when i remove the whitespace, is there another way to that?

Comment: There are the two alternatives listed at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: i think the last alternative to set the font-size to 0 is the best and right way :)